# reveal elements in a container sequentially on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm using [Scroll Reveal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scrollreveal) for on-scroll reveal animation. what I want to do is to reveal child items of a container sequentially when its position is reached. How can I do that? I'm finding it hard to understand its documentation.

This is my code,

```
<div class="container-fluid features" style="padding-bottom: 75px;">
            <h2 style="text-align: center;">Features</h2>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="featureOne">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <h3>Lorem</h3>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <img src="img/cog-upd.png" style="margin-top: 42px;position: absolute;right: -55px;" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="featureTwo">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <h3>Lorem</h3>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <img src="img/task-upd.png" style="margin-top: 50px;position: absolute;right: -55px;" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="featureThree">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <h3>Lorem</h3>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <img src="img/payment-upd.png" style="margin-top: 50px;position: absolute;right: -55px;" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img class="ipad" src="img/ipad-center.png" style="display:block;margin:auto;padding-top: 35px;" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="featureFour">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <img src="img/integration-upd.png" style="margin-top: 50px;position: absolute;left: -55px;" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <h3>Lorem</h3>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="featureFive">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <img src="img/ach-upd.png" style="margin-top: 50px;position: absolute;left: -55px;" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <h3>Lorem</h3>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="featureSix">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <img src="img/config-upd.png" style="margin-top: 50px;position: absolute;left: -55px;" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <h3>Lorem</h3>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Scroll reveal code,

```
<script>
        window.sr = ScrollReveal();
        sr.reveal('.ipad', {
            duration: 500,
            origin: 'bottom'
        });
        sr.reveal('.featureOne', {
            duration: 1000,
            origin: 'left',
            delay: 500
        });
        sr.reveal('.featureTwo', {
            duration: 1000,
            origin: 'left',
            delay: 800
        });
        sr.reveal('.featureThree', {
            duration: 1000,
            origin: 'left',
            delay: 1300
        });
        sr.reveal('.featureFour', {
            duration: 1000,
            origin: 'left',
            delay: 1800
        });
        sr.reveal('.featureFive', {
            duration: 1000,
            origin: 'left',
            delay: 2200
        });
        sr.reveal('.featureSix', {
            duration: 1000,
            origin: 'left',
            delay: 2600
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Do you have an element with `id=solution` in your source?

Comment: yes I do have. Ignore the #solution part. It has nothing to do with it. I'll update my question again removing it. Thanks for asking out @TejasviKarne

Comment: Implementing the source as you posted, it's [working](https://jsfiddle.net/ukczwpyq/) for me. The issue must be caused by some fatal error such as an undefined function or variable that's stopping scrollReveal from being executed. Open up your console and look for errors.

Comment: Look [here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Revealing-Elements-on-Scroll-with-jQuery-scrollReveal.html)

Comment: It is working for me either. My problem is that only when I reach the position of the element I can see it revealing. I want all the elements inside the container to reveal sequentially when I reach the starting position of the container on scroll! @TejasviKarne